# Как поместить галерею картинок в спойлер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, список, gallery

Есть сайт на wordpress и плагин галереи [NextGEN Gallery](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) Хочу сделать так, чтобы выводилось 4 фотки с галереи, а остальные скрывались в спойлере, а по клику на галочке список раскрывался? Это можно сделать с помощью данной галереи или нужна другая?

Comment: это можно сделать с помощью javascript, непринципиально какую галерею использовать

Comment: @Umer логично. вы знаете как это можно сделать?

Comment: дайте ссылку на сайт

Comment: @Umer вот, пожалуйста - http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/30/gallery/

Answer (score 1):

Это нужно делать после загрузки галереи, если на `onload` не сработает

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var height = $('.slideshowlink').height() + $('#ngg-image-0').height() * 2;
  var button = $('<button></button>');
  var gallery = $('.ngg-galleryoverview')
  button.html('Показать все').attr('type', 'button').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0
  });
  button.prependTo(gallery);
  gallery.height(height);
  button.on('click', function() {
    gallery.css('height', 'auto')
  });
})
```

Comment: да, на `onload` не сработало - а как отследить загрузку галереи?